# Explicit from of the Idele generator of a fractional ideal

Tags: number-theory

For any number field $F$, let $\mathfrak{c}$ be a fractional ideal. Then $\mathfrak{c}$ will correspond to an idele element $c$, which is called the idele generator of $\mathfrak{c}$.

My first question is that how $c$ corresponds to $\mathfrak{c}$. Because there is not an isomorphism between idele class group and class group, but only they have the same cardinality. Are there some explanations for this correspondence? It would be better if there are some reference!

And my second question is that can we always choose $c$ to be in the ring of integers $\mathcal{O}$ via the canonical embedding of $\mathcal{O}^{\times}$ into idele group. Especially when $\mathfrak{c}$ is a prime ideal, can its uniformizer be chosen in this way?

Thank you very much!

Comment: The group of fractional ideals is the same as $\Bbb{A}_{F,fin}^\times / \widehat{O_F}^\times$ (finite adeles: discarding the infinite places), the map goes in the opposite direction, sending an idele to a fractional ideal. You can embed the group of fractional ideals into $\Bbb{A}_F^\times$ but it won't be natural/canonical. I don't understand what you mean with choosing $c$ to be in $O$.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! My main problem lying on the infinite part. For example, in the case of $\mathbb{Q}$, we can choose the uniformizer of $(p)$ to be $p$, the infinite place is just p. Now $p\in\mathbb{Z}$, and this is what I mean choosing $c$ to be in $\mathcal{O}$. But in general, for a prime ideal $\mathfrak{p}$ with uniformizer $\pi_{\mathfrak{p}}$, how to describe its infinite place?

Comment: If $\mathfrak{p}$ is not a principal ideal of $O_K$ then there is no equivalent to $p\in \Bbb{Z}$. You set the infinite places as you want, there is no canonical map from the fractional ideals to $\Bbb{A}_F^\times$.